# How do I schedule a method in a spring MVC controller?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have defined various scheduler in my configuration file as follows:

```
<task:executor id="xxxxxExecutor" pool-size="${async.executor.pool.size}"/>

<task:scheduler id="xxxxwwwScheduler" pool-size="1" />

<task:scheduler id="qqqqSchedular" pool-size="1" />

<task:scheduler id="lastScheduler" pool-size="1" />
```

My controller has been annotated via @Controller annotation. How do I specify a particular `Scheduler` in `@Scheduled` annotation in Spring?

p.s. I am trying to schedule a method in a controller using `@Scheduled` annotation.

Comment: Why do you need scheduled in a controller? Why would you need a processing method in your web layer? You cannot specify a specific scheduler in the annotation, the one specified on the `task:annotation-driven` is the one that is always used.

Answer (score 1):

Using multiple schedulers and pointing to them via the `@Scheduled` annotation is unfortunately **not possible**.

However, if you really do need that flexibility, you can define the jobs in XML:

```
<task:scheduled-tasks scheduler="myScheduler">
    <task:scheduled ref="beanA" method="methodA" fixed-delay="5000"/>
</task:scheduled-tasks>
```

That allows you to specify the exact id of the scheduler you need to use, and then simply reference the actual task.

Hope this helps.